# Excel formulas not calculated with OfficeOpenXML

Tags: asp.net, xml, excel

I'm using OfficeOpenXML in Asp.NET.  When trying to create a table in Excel, the subtotal columns return blank as opposed to summing the values in the columns.  Ironically, when I say "Enable Editing" in Excel, the formulas work, and the cells are populated with the subtotal values.  Does anyone know how to get the formulas to work upon opening?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
 `SpreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = True`